# How to find the index of the maximum value in html table and use it to find other information in the same row but another column?

Tags: html, indexing, max

In an HTML table, I have to obtain the maximum value of a column, then its position to find other information in another columns in the same row. Currently, I can find the maximum value but not its position in the column.

I have a classic table ans code like below:

```
<body>
<table id="tableau">
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Score</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>José</td>
                    <td>Maire</td>
                    <td>Paris</td>
                    <td>1000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Lilianne</td>
                    <td>Maire</td>
                    <td>Paris</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Raymond</td>
                    <td>Fourbe</td>
                    <td>Bruxelles</td>
                    <td>123</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>Huguette</td>
                    <td>Fourbe</td>
                    <td>Bruxelles</td>
                    <td>129099</td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
 <button type="buttonmax" id="Score maximum" class="btn btn-info">Afficher le Score maximum</button>

<script>
var myArray = new Array();
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                $("#tableau tr td:nth-child(5)").each(function(i){
                    myArray.push($(this).text());
                });

            document.getElementById("Score maximum").onclick = function(){
             var max = Math.max.apply(Math, $('td:nth-child(5)').map(function(i,elem){ 
                return Number($(elem).text());
             }));

             alert(max);}
             });
</script>
</body>
```

In my opinion, I have to find the index of the maximum value to display the the `Firstname` and `Lastname` of the person who realized this value, situated in the same row but in other columns.

Do you think it's the best way to do this?

I tried diverse codes to obtain the index of max but none worked.

Could you please help me to obtain the index and find the person who realized the best score?

Comment: Your table is missing closing tags, such as </tr>, </tbody>, and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a way to achieve this (altough it is not very performant because it would overwrite the whole object if the current checked value is higher than the previous one).
PLEASE NOTE: I changed your id to "scoremaximum" because you really shouldn't have whitespaces in your id selector.

```
var max = {
    score: 0,
    id: 0,
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
    city: ''
};

$("#tableau tr td:nth-child(5)").each(function(index, elem) {
    var current = parseFloat($(elem).text());
    if(current > max.score) {
        max.score = current;
        max.id = $("#tableau tr td:nth-child(1)")[index].textContent;
        max.firstname = $("#tableau tr td:nth-child(2)")[index].textContent;
        max.lastname = $("#tableau tr td:nth-child(3)")[index].textContent;
        max.city = $("#tableau tr td:nth-child(4)")[index].textContent;
    }
});

$('#scoremaximum').on('click', function() {
  alert("score: " + max.score + ", id: " + max.id + ", firstname: " + max.firstname + ", lastname " + max.lastname + ", city: " + max.city);
});
```

You could increase the performance a little bit if you would add another property to the object that keeps track of the index outside of the loop and update it accordingly to the max.score. Then you could run a callback function after the loop has finished and pass it the max.index. That would look like this:

```
var max = {
    score: 0,
    index: 0,
    id: 0,
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
    city: ''
};

$("#tableau tr td:nth-child(5)").each(function(index, elem) {
    var current = parseFloat($(elem).text());
    if(current > max.score) {
        max.score = current;
        max.index = index;
  }
  return callback(max.index);
});

function callback(index) {
    max.id = $("#tableau tr td:nth-child(1)")[index].textContent;
    max.firstname = $("#tableau tr td:nth-child(2)")[index].textContent;
    max.lastname = $("#tableau tr td:nth-child(3)")[index].textContent;
    max.city = $("#tableau tr td:nth-child(4)")[index].textContent;
}

$('#scoremaximum').on('click', function() {
  alert("score: " + max.score + ", id: " + max.id + ", firstname: " + max.firstname + ", lastname " + max.lastname + ", city: " + max.city);
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KYyyKV

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand your logic but I don't know why your code don't work. I will find why :) thanks it keeps me going!

Comment: my code works. check the codepen. i changed your id "Score maximum" in my example to "scoremaximum" because you shouldnt have whitepsace in an id.

Comment: Yes I saw it on codepen but I did not see where was my mistake in the rest of my code (the maximum request is just a part of my work). I found a big big mistake, which had repercussion on your code and now it perfectly works! Thanks a lot uke5tar :)